# Apache Nifi - How to use properties from JSON in ConvertJSONToSQL?

Tags: apache-nifi

The JSON is an array of objects and each object contains the destination table.

Is it possible do dynamically set the destination table (for each row) ?

[image: Apache Nifi ConvertJSONToSQL]

**Edit**

Payload:

```
[ {
  "dest" : "central.grupo",
  "keys" : "cd_grupo",
  "cd_grupo" : "1",
  "de_grupo" : "MEDICAMENTO",
  "id_op" : "I",
  "cd_int_controle" : 8264651
}, {
  "dest" : "central.grupo",
  "keys" : "cd_grupo",
  "cd_grupo" : "2",
  "de_grupo" : "POPULAR",
  "id_op" : "I",
  "cd_int_controle" : 8264652
}]
```

- `keys` are the update keys;
- `dest` is the destination table

Flow:

[image: Apache Nifi Flow]

Comment: it should be possible but you will have to extract the json atribute for the table and place then in a NiFi attribute - can you show the flow and the json payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

- this is the schemas i created to inject that incoming json - based on the attributes it contains.

```html
create table operations.grupo (
dest varchar(10),
mykeys varchar(10),
cd_grupo varchar(20),
de_grupo varchar(20),
id_op varchar(20),
cd_int_controle varchar(20));

create table operations.grupo1 (
dest varchar(10),
mykeys varchar(10),
cd_grupo varchar(20),
de_grupo varchar(20),
id_op varchar(20),
cd_int_controle varchar(20));
```

**The nifi procs you use would be :**

```
SplitJson >> EvaluateJson(extract dest & keys) >> ConvertJsonToSQL(use the dest & keys attributes) >> PutSQL(just set the connection)
```

This approach requires you to have the column dest and keys in the target table.

If you dont want that you can avoid this using a jolttransformation(clean approach) or you can use evaluatejson to evaluate all json attribute and then a attributestojson to construct the json payload without the dest & keys in the payload.

[image]

This is the evaluatejson proc setup
[image]